# Aligning text and textarea at the same level

Tags: html, css

In the following html, how can I align both the `text` and the `text area` at the same level ?

```
<div>
  <span>Type</span>
  <span> <textarea rows="5" cols="100"> </textarea>
</div>
```

At present, the `text` appears at the foot of `textarea`.

Comment: _"At present, the text appears at the foot of textarea."_ I don't know what you're seeing but in your code "Type" appears before, and above, the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="alignTogether">type</span>

<span class="alignTogether"> "your text area" </span>
```

CSS

```
.alignTogether {
   float: left;
}
```

There is multiple ways of doing this....

another way would be to add the .alignTogether class to your css and then adding the class to your div like this:

```
<div class="alignTogether">
   <span> these will float left </span>
</div>

.alignTogether span{
   float:left;
}
```

I recomend reviewing some css Here:
[CSS Tutorials @ W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp)

Comment: can you please explain your answer

Comment: You need to understand how different positioning effects your elements. There is MANY ways to accomplish different positiong. The different ways you choose may effect layout on the rest of the page so you should look into a variety of methods and see what fits your needs the best. Also inheritance.... GO to the link i provided and run through some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
<div>
  <span>Type</span>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="100"> </textarea>
</div>

span{
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T5tJW/

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` property vertically aligns the element.

Write:

```
.vmiddle{display:inlline-block;vertical-align:top;}

<div>
  <span class="vmiddle">Type</span>
  <textarea class="vmiddle" rows="5" cols="10"> </textarea>
</div>
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UTr7W/1)